# How to merge two data frames in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis

I have two pandas dataframes

```
Unnamed: 0  sentiment   numberagreed    tweetid tweet
0   0   2   6   219584  Apple processa a Samsung no Japão - Notícias -...
1   1   1   3   399249  É O JACKI CHAN !!! RT @user ESSE É DOS MEUS!!!...
2   2   3   3   387155  Eras o samsung galaxy tab e muito lerdo para t...
3   3   3   3   205458  Dizem que a coisa mais triste que o homem enfr...
4   4   3   3   2054404 RAIVA vou ter que ir com meu nike dinovo pra e...

tweetid sent
219584  0.494428
399249  0.789241
387155  0.351972
205458  0.396907
2054404 0.000000
```

They are not the same length and there are some missing values in the second data frame

I want to merge the two data frames based on the `tweetid` and drop the missing values

Comment: It will be easier to get good replies if you ask your questions together with a minimum executable example. I.e. instead of showing the tables preformated, include an example of to create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on='tweetid', how='inner')
```

Because you take the `inner`, non-overlapping parts will be thrown away. `on='tweetid'` merges it on `tweetid`.

Comment: it gives  KeyError: 'tweetid'
How is that !?

Comment: @MuhammedEltabakh thats probably because your column name is different

Comment: @MuhammedEltabakh It means that there is no column named `tweetid`. Make sure you columns are named properly

Comment: yes tweetid is the index of the second data frame and I can only access it using df.index

Comment: Then do a `reset_index()`. Column will be named `tweetid`. Otherwise rename that column

Comment: reset index didn't work, but I got it, I created a new column converted values in tweetid into integers because they were strings and appended it to it and performed the above command and it worked 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an extra character somewhere at the beginning of your file. Are you reading the data from a csv file? Post the source code of how you are reading the data.

or name your columns on both dataframe.

```
df_tweets.columns = ("tweetid", "sent")
```